# ERB not showing instance variable values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

`@user` shows up as `nil` when I display it into HTML. However, it holds the correct values when I output it to the rails server.

*new.html.erb*

```
<% u = @user.username %>
<% puts u %>
<p> <%= u %> </p>

<%= form_with model: @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label 'username', 'Username:' %>
  <%= f.text_field :username, :value => 'Enter Your Username' %>
  <%= f.label 'email', 'Email:' %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, :value => 'example@example.com' %>

  <%= f.label 'password', 'Password:' %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

*schema.rb*

```
 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end
```

*users_controller.rb*

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(whitlisted_user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to new_user_path
    else
      render :new
    end


private 

  def whitlisted_user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
  end
```

Output on rails server

```
Vedant
```

Output on webpage

```
<p> </p>
```

Comment: The code in this question cannot possibly explain this and rather its due to something outside the picture or just bad methodology. Try creating a real verifiable example that reproduces this exact issue. It also appears that your create method is missing the `end` keyword.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I wasnt sure how I'd share enough code without it being overwhelming. Anyways I've added a git link to the project. Hope that it makes it easier to understand. Also thanks for pointing out typo in the create method.

Comment: Another thing, the code in the sample is real code I ran as i tried to debug the issue. I deleted everything in my new.erb.html except those lines and was still facing the same problem

Comment: None of this helps us help you debug it. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself. Otherwise we are just wasting time here on hypotheticals.

Comment: fixed. Hope the question is easier to understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong and posting it here for others.

If you look at the server logs it will have a line

```
Processing by UserController#create as JS.
```

This happens because form_with(unlike form_for & form_tag) submits the data using XHR(Ajax) by default. What was actually happening was that the render was not performing a full page refresh

This was one of the added advantages of using form_with.

[Rails Issue #25197](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25197)

> Full-page changes after submissions are rough. When using Turbolinks,
>   a normal redirect will generate a Turbolinks.visit() call, and
>   otherwise there's SJR. (We could consider having
>   config.action_view.forms_remote_by_default that you could set to
>   false, for people going old school).

There are two ways to display errors now

**(Quick Fix) local: true**

add `local: true` to the form_with code which disables the remote: true by default feature

change

```
<%=form_with model: @user do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%=form_with model: @user, local:true do |f| %>
```

**The better way embracing AJAX**

https://m.patrikonrails.com/do-you-really-need-that-fancy-javascript-framework-e6f2531f8a38